# Less CSS Mixin for positioning with options for corresponding top, left, right, bottom values

Tags: css, mixins, less-css

I've created a Mixin in Less CSS. It can do the following things:

- Set the position-rule of an element.
- Place the element in one of the corners (e.g. *top left*, *bottom right* etc.)
- Alternatively it can set explicit values for `top|right|bottom|left`.

**Usage example:**

```
.test-1 {
    .position(absolute, top, right);
}
```

**Examples showing the resulting CSS:**

```
.position() { position: static; }
.position(relative) { position: relative; }
.position(absolute, top, right) { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: auto; left: auto; right: 0; }
.position(absolute, bottom, left) { position: absolute; top: auto; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: auto; }
.position(fixed, 20px, 50%) { position: fixed; top: 20px; right: 50%; }
.position(fixed, 10px, null, null, 10%) { fixed: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10%; }
.position(absolute, 10px, -, -, 10%) { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10%; }
```

**The Mixin:**

```
.position(@position: static; @a: null; @b: null; @c: null; @d: null) {
    position: @position;

    & when (top = @a) {
        top: 0;
        bottom: auto;
    }

    & when (bottom = @a) {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    & when (left = @b) {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
    }

    & when (right = @b) {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }

    & when not (null = @a) and not (~'-' = @a) and not (top = @a) and not (bottom = @a) {
        top: @a;
    }

    & when not (null = @b) and not (~'-' = @b) and not (top = @b) and not (bottom = @b) {
        right: @b;
    }

    & when not (null = @c) and not (~'-' = @c) {
        bottom: @c;
    }

    & when not (null = @d) and not (~'-' = @d) {
        left: @d;
    }
}
```

I've also created a shortahand version `.p()`, which can be called instead of `.position()`:

```
.p(@position: static; @a: null; @b: null; @c: null; @d: null) {
    .position(@position; @a; @b; @c; @d);
}
```

**My questions are:**

- Is this a useful Mixin?
- Or is it a bad practie to create Mixins like this?
- Is it too complicated or too hard to understand?
- Can this be optimized or shortend?

---

Even though most of the time I need to use `top` and `left` for positioning, I found it more related to other CSS rules like `margin` when the values are sorted clockwise like `top|right|bottom|left`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this a useful Mixin?** Depends on if you need it a lot.

**Or is it a bad practice to create Mixins like this?** Nothing is bad practice if it helps you float your boat.

**Is it too complicated or too hard to understand?** Not really, but seems like you'll often have to lookup the generated CSS to fix positioning problems. F.e. I'm not a big fan of `10px, null, null, 10%`, I know it's NESW, but still... Wouldn't it be better to have `.position(fixed, top 10px, left 10%)` if that is possible?

**Can this be optimized or shortened?** Probably yes, but why do premature optimization if the use-case is unknown?